# Suppress all output from the compute.es functions

Tags: r

I'm using the `compute.es` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compute.es/compute.es.pdf) to compute effect sizes. Now, when using one of the functions from this package, the result is printed even though you assign it to a vector, and I would like to surpress this.

For example,

```
library("compute.es")
mes(5,5,5,5,5,5,level=95,dig=2,id=NULL,data=NULL)
```

prints a lot of information. By using `capture.output` like so

```
library("compute.es")
capture.output(mes(5,5,5,5,5,5,level=95,dig=2,id=NULL,data=NULL))
```

a lot of it gets suppressed, but not all. I've had no luck with `sink()` (which breaks the whole function) or `invisible()` either.

How can I suppress all printed information from this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 0.2-4 of the `compute.es` package has a 'verbose' argument, so e.g.:

```
require(compute.es) # VERSION => 0.2-4

des(.3, 30, 30, verbose=FALSE)  # WILL SUPPRESS PRINTING TO CONSOLE
```

Comment: Thank you for updating this package!

Answer (score 3):

This function is really bi-polar. Some things are printed using `cat`, others using `message`. In addition to what you've tried you can also try `suppressMessages`.

This worked for me.

```
x <- capture.output(suppressMessages(mes(5,5,5,5,5,5,level=95,dig=2,id=NULL,data=NULL)))
```

Alternatively, you can hack the function (use the source!) and cut out all the `cat` and `message` statements. Another way would be to add another argument to the function (like `verbose`) and turn on/off messages by putting them inside an `if` clause. E.g.

```
if (!is.null(data)) {
  if (verbose) {
    cat("\n")
    message("    EFFECT SIZE CALCULATION (FOR VECTOR INPUT)")
    cat("\n")
  }
...
```

Comment: What an inconvenient function.  You'd think they would have written a `printResult` argument in for the result.

Comment: Thanks, using suppressMessages() did the trick, although I had to place capture.output() around the whole statement and the suppressMessages() around only the function itself (and not the `x <-` part), otherwise, I got the former printed output assigned to the variable. I'll email the author and see if he/she is interested in putting in a printResult argument, as RichardScriven suggested.